# Unable to update database in InnoDb

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am using phpMyadmin and innoDb engine. I have already done insertion and deletion. But i can't update anything. I couldn't understand the error.I have called the updatestudent from updatestudent.php .  The goes to the function updatestudent but it returns error and update not successful.

updateStudent.php

```
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['mobileno']) and isset($_POST['sem']) and isset($_POST['section']) and isset($_POST['usn'])){
        $db = new DbOperations(); 

        if($db->updateStudent($_POST['mobileno'], $_POST['sem'], $_POST['section'], $_POST['usn'])){
            $user = $db->getStudentByUsername($_POST['name']);
            $response['error'] = false; 
            $response['name'] = $user['name'];
            $response['email'] = $user['email'];
            $response['mobileno'] = $user['mobileno'];
            $response['dept'] = $user['dept'];
            $response['sem'] = $user['sem'];
            $response['usn'] = $user['usn'];
            $response['section']=$user['section'];
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "Update was not successful";         
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

updateStudent function

```
public function updateStudent($mobileno, $sem, $section, $usn){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `student` SET mobileno = ? AND sem = ? AND section = ? WHERE usn = ? ");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$mobileno, $sem, $section, $usn);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->get_result();

        }
```

Comment: can you show the `error`

Comment: What does this have to do with PhpMyAdmin? That's a tool for interactively viewing and updating the database, it has nothing to do with writing your own PHP scripts.

Comment: Columns in update statement are divided by comma not by `AND`

Comment: `$stmt->get_result()` always returns `FALSE` for `UPDATE` statements. It only returns a useful value for `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

your sql statment is not correct:

```
UPDATE `student` SET mobileno = ? AND sem = ? AND section = ? WHERE usn = ?
```

should be

```
UPDATE `student` SET mobileno = ? , sem = ?, section = ? WHERE usn = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

`return $stmt->get_result();` is not the correct way to tell if the `UPDATE` was successful. The documentation of [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) says:

> Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure. The mysqli_errno() function can be used to distinguish between the two types of failure.

So for an `UPDATE` query, it will always return `FALSE`. You need to call `mysqli_errno()` to find out if it was actually successful:

```
return $this->conn->errno == 0;
```

You also need to correct the syntax of the `UPDATE` query, it should be:

```
UPDATE `student` SET mobileno = ? , sem = ?, section = ? WHERE usn = ?
```

Since the query has incorrect syntax, `prepare()` is failing, so `$stmt` is `FALSE` and you should be getting an error when you call `$stmt->bind_param()`.